# Get XML element name and the attribute value using SQL XPATH query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

Given an XML type string such as

```
declare @xml xml

SET @xml = 
'<PO>
  <Amount type="approved">10.00</Amount>
  <Year type="">2013</Year>
  <GeneralNotes>
    <Note>
      <NoteText type="instruction">CallVendor</NoteText>
      <Date type="">1-1-2013</Date>
    </Note>
    <Note type="">
      <NoteText type="instruction">ShipNow</NoteText>
      <Date type="">2-2-2013</Date>
    </Note>
  </GeneralNotes>
</PO>'
```

I want to get every element and its attribute if it has one.  My desired output (without duplicates) is

```
ElementName   ElementAttribute

PO  
Amount   approved
Note     instruction
```

I've tried code similar to this line

```
SELECT T.doc.query('fn:local-name(.)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('PO//*[1]') AS T(doc)
```

This brings in duplicates and I am not sure how to select the attribute value. I only need the first occurrence  (i.e,. `GeneralNotes/Note[1]`). I have a much large file with many other element names so I do not want to parse them out individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       T.doc.value('fn:local-name(..)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ElementName,
       T.doc.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as ElementAttribute 
FROM @xml.nodes('PO//@*[1]') AS T(doc)
WHERE T.doc.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') <> ''
```

Result:

```
ElementName     ElementAttribute
--------------- ----------------
Amount          approved
NoteText        instruction
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
    a.c.value('local-name(..)', 'nvarchar(max)') as ElementName,
    a.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as ElementAttribute
from @xml.nodes('//@*[. != ""]') as a(c)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25226)</kbd>**

Comment: Very helpful and also the answer.